# changing the size of my bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, sizing

i have a bar chart in R and i need to widen the size of the entire chart which is being printed to a png with rounded corners.  Anyone know how i can widen this chart while maintaining the rounded format?

```
Cairo(464,325,file='TopSLperformersChart.png',type="png", bg="white")
print(TopSLperformersChart)
grid.roundrect(height=0.99, width=0.99,gp=gpar(fill="#00000000", col="black", lwd=3))
```

Comment: Replace `Cairo(464,...` with, say, `Cairo(600,...`?